# Dynamic content not displaying in View - React JS

Tags: reactjs

I'm building an application based on user survey in React JS.

All the questions are coming from API as JSON response

```
  const data = {
    preQuestions: {
      landingPage: {
        heading: 'This is the ladning page',
        buttons: {
          yesButton: {
            text: 'yes',
            action: '1A',
          },
          noButton: {
            text: 'No',
            action: '1B',
          },
        },
      },
      '1A': {
        heading: 'This is the 1A Component',
        buttons: {
          yesButton: {
            text: 'yes',
            action: '1C',
          },
          noButton: {
            text: 'No',
            action: '1D',
          },
        },
      },
      '1B': {
        heading: 'This is the 1B Component',
        buttons: {
          yesButton: {
            text: 'yes',
            action: '1C',
          },
          noButton: {
            text: 'No',
            action: '1D',
          },
        },
      },
      '1C': {
        heading: 'This is the 1C Component',
        buttons: {
          yesButton: {
            text: 'yes',
            action: '1A',
          },
          noButton: {
            text: 'No',
            action: '1B',
          },
        },
      },
      '1D': {
        heading: 'This is the 1D Component',
        buttons: {
          yesButton: {
            text: 'yes',
            action: '1B',
          },
          noButton: {
            text: 'No',
            action: '1C',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };
```

I wanted to display only 1st question by default and based on the user response I need to load the second question on same page, where use can able to see the previous question .

Basically I wanted to stack all the questions one below the other based on user actions.

But current with my logic, When user selects the next question, prev question getting disappeared.

Below is my code,

```
  const [active, setActive] = React.useState<any>(
    data.preQuestions['landingPage']
  );

  const content = data.preQuestions;

  const loadNextCompnent = (actionId) => {
    setActive(actionId);
  };

  const renderQustionComponent = () => {
    <a href="#">Previous question</a>
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{active?.heading}</h1>
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            loadNextCompnent(content[active?.buttons?.yesButton?.action])
          }
        >
          {active.buttons.yesButton.text}{' '}
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            loadNextCompnent(content[active?.buttons?.noButton?.action])
          }
        >
          {active.buttons.noButton.text}{' '}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return <div>{renderQustionComponent()}</div>;
```

How Can I stack all the questions one below the other ? Please help.

Working Stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-z8clfj

Comment: Use an array https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-txmqnk?file=App.tsx

Comment: Yes great, works fine, also can please help me with the previous question ?

Comment: When clicked on Previous question it should move to the above question with smooth scroll